# got an error when i tried to call the value with go lang

Tags: json, go

I just starting learn this Go Lang programming, and now i'm stuck with the [] things, I tried to create a blog using the Go Lang and i'm using a template, there's no problem with the template, it just I want to append a data that I got from json file.

If I just take the data and send it through the file it's already done, but the problem is when I tried to append the slug to the data (because the json file i got no slug url in it.

That's why I want to get the title of the post then make a slug with it, then

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gosimple/slug"
    "html/template"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

type Blog struct {
    Title  string
    Author string
    Header string
}

type Posts struct {
    Posts []Post `json:"posts"`
}

type Post struct {
    Title       string `json:"title"`
    Author      string `json:"author"`
    Content     string `json:"content"`
    PublishDate string `json:"publishdate"`
    Image       string `json:"image"`
}

type BlogViewModel struct {
    Blog  Blog
    Posts []Post
}

func loadFile(fileName string) (string, error) {
    bytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fileName)

    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    return string(bytes), nil
}

func loadPosts() []Post {
    jsonFile, err := os.Open("source/posts.json")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Successfully open the json file")
    defer jsonFile.Close()

    bytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(jsonFile)

    var post []Post
    json.Unmarshal(bytes, &post)

    return post
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    blog := Blog{Title: "asd", Author: "qwe", Header: "zxc"}
    posts := loadPosts()

    viewModel := BlogViewModel{Blog: blog, Posts: posts}

    t, _ := template.ParseFiles("template/blog.html")
    t.Execute(w, viewModel)
}
```

The error is show in the main function

```
func main() {

    posts := loadPosts()

    for i := 0; i < len(posts.Post); i++ { // it gives me this error posts.Post undefined (type []Post has no field or method Post)

        fmt.Println("Title: " + posts.Post[i].Title)
    }
    // http.HandleFunc("/", handler)

    // fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("template"))
    // http.Handle("/assets/css/", fs)
    // http.Handle("/assets/js/", fs)
    // http.Handle("/assets/fonts/", fs)
    // http.Handle("/assets/images/", fs)
    // http.Handle("/assets/media/", fs)

    // fmt.Println(http.ListenAndServe(":9000", nil))

}
```

I already try to solved it a couple of hours but I hit the wall, I think it's possible but I just don't find the way, I don't know what is the good keyword to solve the problem.
And I don't if I already explain good enough or not. Please help me, thank you

This is the JSON file format

```
{
  "posts": [
    {
      "title": "sapien ut nunc",
      "author": "Jeni",
      "content": "jgwilt0@mapquest.com",
      "publishdate": "26.04.2017",
      "image": "http://dummyimage.com/188x199.png/cc0000/ffffff"
    },
    {
      "title": "mus vivamus vestibulum sagittis",
      "author": "Analise",
      "content": "adonnellan1@biblegateway.com",
      "publishdate": "13.03.2017",
      "image": "http://dummyimage.com/182x113.bmp/ff4444/ffffff"
    }
  ]
}
```

[image: This is the directory]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're loadPost method returns `[]Post`. Your definition of `Post` does not contain the `attribute Post`. Your `Posts` struct does.

Here is a modified working example. I didn't define your other structures for brevity.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

var rawJson = `{
  "posts": [
    {
      "title": "sapien ut nunc",
      "author": "Jeni",
      "content": "jgwilt0@mapquest.com",
      "publishdate": "26.04.2017",
      "image": "http://dummyimage.com/188x199.png/cc0000/ffffff"
    },
    {
      "title": "mus vivamus vestibulum sagittis",
      "author": "Analise",
      "content": "adonnellan1@biblegateway.com",
      "publishdate": "13.03.2017",
      "image": "http://dummyimage.com/182x113.bmp/ff4444/ffffff"
    }
  ]
}`

type Data struct {
    Posts []struct {
        Title       string `json:"title"`
        Author      string `json:"author"`
        Content     string `json:"content"`
        Publishdate string `json:"publishdate"`
        Image       string `json:"image"`
    } `json:"posts"`
}

func loadFile(fileName string) (string, error) {
    bytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fileName)

    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return string(bytes), nil
}

func loadData() (Data, error) {
    var d Data
    // this is commented out so that i can load raw bytes as an example
    /*
        f, err := os.Open("source/posts.json")
        if err != nil {
            return d, err
        }
        defer f.Close()

        bytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(f)
    */

    // replace rawJson with bytes in prod
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(rawJson), &d)
    return d, nil
}

func main() {
    data, err := loadData()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for i := 0; i < len(data.Posts); i++ {
        fmt.Println("Title: " + data.Posts[i].Title)
    }

    /*
    // you can also range over the data.Posts if you are not modifying the data then using the index is not necessary. 
    for _, post := range data.Posts {
        fmt.Println("Title: " + post.Title)
    }
    */

}
```

modified just for files

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

type Data struct {
    Posts []struct {
        Title       string `json:"title"`
        Author      string `json:"author"`
        Content     string `json:"content"`
        Publishdate string `json:"publishdate"`
        Image       string `json:"image"`
    } `json:"posts"`
}


func loadData() (Data, error) {
    var d Data
    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("source/posts.json")
    if err != nil {
        return d, err
    }

    err = json.Unmarshal(b, &d)
    if err != nil {
        return d, err
    }

    return d, nil
}

func main() {
    data, err := loadData()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for _, post := range data.Posts {
        fmt.Println("Title: " + post.Title)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tried it and it working, but when I tried to get the json file why the len function show it 0? [func loadData](https://i.imgur.com/zCK4RHi.png) I already make it the same as yours [func main](https://i.imgur.com/Rg3USd1.png) but the result is [output](https://i.imgur.com/0YkayTA.png)

Comment: Did you uncomment the commented code above? I'm going to edit it work with a file.

Comment: yeah i uncomment the code, because i need to get the data from a file. but isn't it the same? because what inside the file is the same with the rawJson you make right?

Comment: I added a cleaner version that's just for files.  Assuming your path is correct and the contents in the file exists in the same exact format your JSON example from above is then all should be well.

Comment: ah i see, so the `os.Open` is the wrong function I assume, but now why it gives me this error **json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type main.Data**

Comment: ah nvm, my mistake, i delete the part of json file, that's why it gives the error . 1 more questions, is it possible to put another struct in `type data struct`? for now it have only **posts** how about if i put another **users struct**?

Comment: Yes it's possible and you can embed it or define a new attribute of that new type

https://www.goinggo.net/2014/05/methods-interfaces-and-embedded-types.html

Comment: Applause for adding the missing error checks of the original code.